# Config file looks like json but not json. I am looking for a parser

Tags: python, json, resnet

I recently came across a config file while working with ResNet deep learning. The file looks like json but some objects starting without ':' (colon). json.loads does not work. Here is the file.

```
model {
  ssd {
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
    num_classes: 5
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    anchor_generator {
      multiscale_anchor_generator {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        anchor_scale: 4.0
        aspect_ratios: [1.0, 2.0, 0.5]
        scales_per_octave: 2
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 640
        width: 640
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      weight_shared_convolutional_box_predictor {
        depth: 256
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.6
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.01
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            scale: true,
            decay: 0.997,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
        num_layers_before_predictor: 4
        kernel_size: 3
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_resnet152_v1_fpn_keras'
      fpn {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
      }
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.0004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          scale: true,
          decay: 0.997,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          alpha: 0.25
          gamma: 2.0
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
  #fine_tune_checkpoint: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/resnet152.ckpt-1"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  batch_size: 16
  sync_replicas: true
  startup_delay_steps: 0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  use_bfloat16: true
  num_steps: 25000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_crop_image {
      min_object_covered: 0.0
      min_aspect_ratio: 0.75
      max_aspect_ratio: 3.0
      min_area: 0.75
      max_area: 1.0
      overlap_thresh: 0.0
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: .04
          total_steps: 25000
          warmup_learning_rate: .013333
          warmup_steps: 2000
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
}

train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "data/annotations/type_level/label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "data/annotations/type_level/train.record"
  }
}
eval_config {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "data/annotations/type_level/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "data/annotations/type_level/test.record"
  }
}
```

Please help me with at least name of this file format. Cant figure out how to parse it. Should I write custom parser?
Thanks

Comment: It's a long way from being valid JSON. The property names and string values would all need double-quotes as well, for that to be the case. Also there's no coherent structure - it's a set of separate objects, with no link between them, no comma-separation, or array wrapped around them. It's a completely custom format, I've never seen that before. Perhaps if it's got something to do with an existing software library you've been using, the people behind that project can help you with it? Presumably someone somewhere knows how to parse it already, otherwise it wouldn't exist.

Comment: Looks like yaml, where indentation has been replaced by curly braces

Answer (score 1):

This is a TensorFlow model config file. It name is probably something similar to `pipeline.config`. See [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs) for more of such config examples. The way you "parse" it is actually to load it with the `model_from_config` function from TensorFlow (see [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/model_from_config)). Then you can change the parameters of the model and store the model back to disk with `save_model`.